Is the Buddha nature the exact opposite of René Descartes' view?
French philosopher René Descartes is famous for saying "Je pense, donc je suis." (I think, therefore I am.).
Is this in fact the exact opposite of the concept of the Buddha nature, with something like "I am. But unfortunately I can think." being the more appropriate idea?

Descartes seems to be saying that because he can think he is aware that he exists.
My (possibly mistaken) impression of Buddha nature is that everything exists, but thinking about one's own existence can disrupt or interfere with that existence.

Who said “ I am, but unfortunately I can think.”?

I’m voting to close this question because it contains the type of befuddlement expressed by Vachagotta in SN 44.10 which the Buddha refused to address. In other words,  this question does not appear to be about Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice, within the scope defined in the help center.

Buddha nature is conditional. Any kind of nature is conditional. I don’t from where you have picked up the view that “ I am, but unfortunately I can think.” Most people are deeply engrossed in fulfilling cravings. Until attempts are made to uproot cravings Buddha nature can not arise.
Mind is one the six senses. It is natural for thoughts to arise, just as it is natural for feelings to arise.
I think therefore I am is wrong.
The Truth is : Thoughts are not me , mine or myself. Just like the feelings. Feelings are not me , mine or myself.
Having good thoughts is necessary to attain Nibbana. Essentially you should aim to not to return to any kind of existence with no complaints against anyone.
